# Spring batch to read multiple csv files into different databases table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-excel

I have multiple excels which are different from each other. One has columns like segment, country, product and the other one has application, environment, database and so on... I want to read them and insert them into different tables say t1 and t2 respectively. I am looking for something which can solve this issue.
I have seen many tutorials/blogs etc which shows to read and write single excel into database or multiples files but the structure of excels are same ie columns are same.

Comment: You can create a Step with FlatFileItemReader and JdbcBatchItemWriter and run it in a loop for different files.

Answer (score 0):

The input files are differents, so you would want to create different steps to process them. These steps can be executed in parallel since the read/write operations are independent.